# MySQL Won't Roll Back Transactions

Tags: mysql, transactions, rollback, autocommit

I spend a lot of time developing in MySQL Workbench.  For the past couple of weeks, I've been working on some stored procedures and testing them in rolled back transactions.  But, the changes made by the procedure are being committed even though I've been rolling them back.  I found a suggestion to run 'set autocommit = 0;' and that worked for while.  But, now, that isn't working either.  I run the following, then even when I run the select statements on another computer running Workbench, the changes made by the procedure are shown.

set autocommit = 0;

start transaction;

call TestProc(129,131);

select * from Table1;

select * from Table2;

rollback;

I have never needed the "set autocommit = 0" line before and it messes things up until I reset it to 1.  But, as I said, that isn't even working now.

I wonder if I need to reset statistics or something.  I've trued "Flush Tables;" and "Flush Query Cache;"; but, the problem persists.  I'm guessing this is a either a maintenance issue that I don't know how to fix.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: you need more detail than this

Answer (score 0):

[14.3.2 Statements That Cannot Be Rolled Back](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-roll-back.html)

Some statements cannot be rolled back. In general, these include ... or stored routines (*I mean your **call TestProc(129,131);***).
You should design your transactions not to include such statements.

I hope it was helpful info.

Comment: Leonid,  Thank you for your reply.  However, I have been running stored procedures inside of rolled back transactions for a couple of years without problems, including procedures that update, insert, and delete records.  I just started encountering this issue a couple of weeks ago.